# CSS wrong appearance of border-radius on a nested div

Tags: html, css

Using the following HTML I need to:

- Make sure that the border of `target div` (pink) is adjacent of the `wrapper-target` red border div.
- Must work on any value of border-radius.

Considering that:

- I am using `box-sizing: border-box;` but can be also reset to a default value.
- I cannot change the `border-radius` property of the `target` div.

```css
*,
*:after,
*:before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper-target" style="position:absolute;top:100px;left:100px;width:250px;height:250px;border-radius:50px;border:25px solid red;">
  <div id="target" style="position:relative;width:100%;height:100%;background-color:plum;border-radius:inherit">
  </div>
</div>
```

NOTES:

- I do not need to make a circle in this specific example :).

Comment: Your wrapper-target has 250px width and height but 100px border-radius. To have it round you have to use 125px border-radius ;-) or just use `border-radius: 50%;` this is much better for round elements as you can change the width and height and it still fits.

Comment: I do not need to have a circle

Comment: basically u wanna get rid of the white space between order and target div?

Comment: @Sowmya correct! I made and edit to my question, I change the radius for the border, so there is no confusion :)

Comment: @GibboK as you have made border-radius: 50%; for first div and for second div if you make border-radius: 15%; if may perfectly fit with in wrapper-target

Comment: @IqbalPasha thanks, please read my edit... I cannot change the border-radius property of the target div.

Comment: @GibboK: If `border-radius` on target cannot be changed then I think the only option is to make the child the same dimensions as parent (using `calc`), positioning it and then clipping `overflow` in parent. I've added a sample of that to my answer and maybe it'd help you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Part 1 of the problem:** (Child becoming a round in original demo)

The problem is because of the `box-sizing: border-box`. When this is set, the defined height, width of the box (250 x 250px) is considered as inclusive of the width of the `border` and the `padding`. So, the element's actual content area is only 200px x 200px (excluding 50px for horizontal & vertical borders).

Thus the child `div` will only have a size of 200px x 200px (*this can be verified in Dev tools*). When a `border-radius` of `100px` is inherited from parent, it becomes a round as that is half of its dimensions.

So, the `border-radius` cannot be inherited for the child if the shape has to be maintained. It should be set as `80px` (approximate). (*Initially I had mentioned that a value of 76px was working better and that I was trying to find out the reason for it - please refer to Part 2 for the reason*.)

```css
*,
*:after,
*:before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper-target"       
     style="position:absolute;
            top:100px;left:100px;
            width:250px;height:250px;
            border-radius:100px;
            border:25px solid red;">
  <div id="target" 
       style="position:relative;
              width:100%;height:100%;
              background-color:plum;
              border-radius:76px;">
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**Part 2 of the problem:** (even when border-box is removed, it leaves a gap)

This is because the assigned `border-radius` is the radius of the outer border and not that of the inner border. The ***inner border radius*** is calculated as outer border radius minus border thickness.

As per [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#corner-shaping):

> The padding edge (inner border) radius is the outer border radius minus the corresponding border thickness.

So, the child's `border-radius` need to be equal to the ***inner border radius*** of the parent. That is, the child's `border-radius` should be `75px` (100px - 25px thickness of border).

This is also why a `border-radius` of 76px worked better than the 80px as mentioned earlier. 76px is closer to 75px than 80px :)

---

**Solution without changing border radius of target:**

If `border-radius: inherit` on the child (target) cannot be changed then the only option is to make the child the same dimensions as parent (using `calc`), positioning it and then clipping the overflow in parent.

```css
*,
*:after,
*:before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper-target" style="position:absolute;
            top:100px;left:100px;
            width:250px;height:250px;
            border-radius:100px;
            border:25px solid red;
            overflow: hidden;">
  <div id="target" style="position:relative;
              width:calc(100% + 50px);height: calc(100% + 50px);
              top: -25px; left: -25px;
              background-color:plum;
              border-radius:inherit;">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: many thanks for your solution which pointed me out the right direction, please look at this https://jsfiddle.net/ahd5hwrh/3/ it works even without overflow:hidden .... what do you think about padding approch?

Comment: @GibboK: You're welcome mate. I've also added more details about how the child's border radius should be assigned/calculated into my answer. Coming to the `padding` approach, I am not too sure if that will work in all browsers. `padding` on all 4 sides should generally be working only on block elements (which a `img` is not). So, can't be sure.

Comment: I appreciate your feedback, have a nice day!

Comment: @GibboK: [This](https://jsfiddle.net/ahd5hwrh/4/) could and should work in all browsers (inspired by your fiddle). I have changed `padding` with `border: 25px solid transparent`. A transparent border will cause no problems, maintain the corner shape (radius) and even `img` can have borders :)

Answer (score 2):

```css
*, *:after, *:before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper-target" style="position:absolute;top:100px;left:100px;width:250px;height:250px;border-radius:50%;border:25px solid red;">
  <div id="target" style="position:relative;width:100%;height:100%;background-color:plum;border-radius:inherit"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: sorry, does not solve my issue, you are assuming a circle, but my issue happen with any arbitration value of border-radius

Answer (score 2):

Try adding same bg color of target div to main div.

```
<div id="wrapper-target" style="position:absolute;top:100px;left:100px;width:250px;height:250px;border-radius:50px;border:25px solid red; background-color:plum;">
        <div id="target" style="position:relative;width:100%;height:100%;background-color:plum;border-radius:inherit">
        </div>
    </div>
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/f0j9ba2q/)**

Comment: Thanks for this solution, but in my real application it should work also for image tag, (sorry I did not mention in my original question)

Comment: @GibboK in that case use a common color and make it work for both image and div [image fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f0j9ba2q/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Set value of border-radius in %, not in px, if you want to make a circle.

Comment: Thanks, but I do not need to make a circle, please look at my edit in my question.

Answer (score 1):

You inherit the border-radius with a fixed value while the child element has other dimensions. Calculate the border in percent. Use `border-radius:40%;` on your wrapper.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I cannot change the border-radius for the inner element as mentioned in my question.

Comment: No, use 40% in the outer and let it be inherit to the inner.
The 40% is calculated by the wrappers 250px width and the 100px border-radius. Take a look: https://jsfiddle.net/wugpnzeL/

Comment: Looking at your  jsfiddle I stil see a gap between the two divs, they should be perfectly adjacent

Answer (score 1):

Maby this wil help. The css is now set in a external file.

The `border-radius:inherit;` checks the border-radius that is already there. so it sets to that border-radius.

```css
*,
*:after,
*:before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#wrapper-target {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  border: 25px solid red;
  background-color: plum;
}
#target {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: plum;
  border-radius: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper-target">
  <div id="target">
  </div>
</div>
```