# Strange white line overflow: hidden

Tags: html, css, sass

I made a little CSS drawing of BB-8:

http://codepen.io/simonschiller/pen/LRqKZg

Now there is a strange white line inside the body which appears because I set the overflow to hidden in the #bb8-body div. How do I get rid of it?

Here is the css for the div:

```
#bb8-body
    position: absolute
    border-radius: 50%
    border: 12px solid $color
    z-index: 200
    overflow: hidden
    background-color: $background
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove border around circular image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36311444/remove-border-around-circular-image)

Comment: The solution in the post you mentioned is to set a background-color, I can't do that in my drawing